# The rotation of image after take photo

Tags: android

I use the camera API to take photos. The orientation of the preview(surfaceview) is ok. But when I view a photo that I've taken, it's the wrong orientation.
So how can I fix it? I use the HTC sensation.

p.s. like this:
When I take a photo in portrait, it displays at an angle of 90 degrees counter-clockwise.

When I take photo at an angle of 90 degrees counter-clockwise, it displays in portrait.

Comment: Can you please put photo which is wrong rotation . So we can get better Idea .

Answer (score 0):

check my answer for this question [to rotate image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12044717/886001)

you use a `Matrix` to apply the required rotation. if you don't the right orientation you just use `ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION` to get it then you rotate your image

Comment: where should i implement this code? i tried at public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) and save. but it wrong. i just want it right rotation like preview

Comment: you can use this to get the bitmap to use inside your `ImageView` used for preview..Is this clear?

Comment: i see that. but do you have any idea about saving right image (image with right orientation) when you finish call onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) ?