# RenderScript does not build ScriptC file on android studio

Tags: android, renderscript

I am trying to integrate the answer which uses render script in the following link to my project. But rotator.rs does not generate the ScriptC_rotator file. How can I integrate this?

[Android: rotate image without loading it to memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044674/android-rotate-image-without-loading-it-to-memory)

My Gradle (I can import  android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript and
android.support.v8.renderscript.Allocation fine)

```
 compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.XXXX"
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 23
        renderscriptTargetApi 22
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        renderscriptNdkModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

renderscriptNdkModeEnabled should be false. If you have it set to true, you will get ScriptC_rotator.cpp instead.