# Android Renderscript Type mismatch with U8_4

Tags: java, android, renderscript

I tried to implement the Renderscript from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29734593/5341805)

So my Renderscript looks like the following:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(bavarit.app.cinnac)

rs_allocation inImage;
int inWidth;
int inHeight;

uchar4 __attribute__ ((kernel)) rotate_90_clockwise (uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    uint32_t inX  = inWidth - 1 - y;
    uint32_t inY = x;
    const uchar4 *out = rsGetElementAt(inImage, inX, inY);
    return *out;
}

uchar4 __attribute__ ((kernel)) rotate_270_clockwise (uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    uint32_t inX = y;
    uint32_t inY = inHeight - 1 - x;

    const uchar4 *out = rsGetElementAt(inImage, inX, inY);
    return *out;
}
```

The Javacode like this:

```
private static Bitmap rotateBitmapNew(Bitmap bitmap, Context ctx) {
    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(ctx);
    ScriptC_imageRotation script = new ScriptC_imageRotation(rs);
    script.set_inWidth(bitmap.getWidth());
    script.set_inHeight(bitmap.getHeight());
    Allocation sourceAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(
            rs, bitmap, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT
    );
    bitmap.recycle();
    script.set_inImage(sourceAllocation);

    int targetHeight = bitmap.getWidth();
    int targetWidth = bitmap.getHeight();
    Bitmap.Config config = bitmap.getConfig();
    Bitmap target = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight, config);
    final Allocation targetAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(
            rs, target, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT
    );

    script.forEach_rotate_90_clockwise(targetAllocation, targetAllocation);
    targetAllocation.copyTo(target);
    rs.destroy();
    return target;
}
```

But when I call this function, I get this error

```
android.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Type mismatch with U8_4!
```

I tried to debug this and find the error, and I found the source was this line in the ScriptC_imageRotation.java class

```
public void forEach_rotate_90_clockwise(Allocation ain, Allocation aout, Script.LaunchOptions sc) {
    // check ain
    if (!ain.getType().getElement().isCompatible(__U8_4)) {
        throw new RSRuntimeException("Type mismatch with U8_4!");
    }
    ...
}
```

Since I have no experience with RenderScript, I could only google, but nothing to this error could be found. Maybe one of you guys has a clue.
What I think I can say is that the type of the Allocation is incorrect, when I logged out the `.getType().getElement()` of the allocation, it was something like U_5_6_5. Maybe thats helpful for somebody who understands this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The renderscript code is expecting to have `RGBA_888` as the element type (since you are using `uchar4` as your input/output type.)  The provided `Bitmap` is in RGB 565 format, so the element type set for the renderscript `Allocation` by `createFromBitmap()` is being set to `RGB_565`.

You need to make sure your source `Bitmap` is in ARGB 8888 format since your target `Bitmap` is created using the source's `Bitmap.Config` and the RS code is expecting the source `Allocation` to also be in this format.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you so much, that was what I was thinking, but due to my lack of skills in this area, I wanted to see it confirmed :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help you out.

Comment: Can you tell me how to adjust the renderscript for the RGB 565 format? Which datatype do I have to use?

Comment: I don't know offhand, you'd have to dig into how it is packed in the allocation and element type.