# Android Studio | CPP file errors error: undefined reference to 'AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels' In bitmap library

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use [AndroidJniBitmapOperations](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AndroidJniBitmapOperations) library.
But I'm a Junior Dev, with no knowledge in the NDK, JNI world.

I succeed to resolve a few errors like 'UnsatisfiedLinkError', but Now I'm getting a new one when I trying to build:

> error: undefined reference to 'AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels'

Also I get a few errors inside the CPP file:

1."Incorrect type for parameter 'prarmeterName', which should have type 'jint'.

2."Add extern 'C'"

But I don't sure if the last 2 are important.

Help me to update this library, because its important and talked in SO several times, like: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044674/android-rotate-image-without-loading-it-to-memory/29734593#29734593).

The link for the library it self:
https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AndroidJniBitmapOperations

All what I have done until now is:
https://github.com/LiorA1/MyRevApp

Comment: Thank you for providing all the necessary information in the question. It might seem obvious to do so, but this is by a pretty wide margin one of the best questions I've seen asked here in quite some time. Thanks for putting in the effort!

Comment: to be honest I was afraid that it will be deleted..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to link the library that provides that API. In https://github.com/LiorA1/MyRevApp/blob/master/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt, copy the code that you have for the logging library like so:

```
find_library(log-lib log)
find_library(jnigraphics-lib jnigraphics)
target_link_libraries(JniBitmapOperationsLibrary ${log-lib} ${jnigraphics-lib})
```

Although I think the template code is actually overly complicated here and you can simplify to just:

```
target_link_libraries(JniBitmapOperationsLibrary -llog -ljnigraphics)
```

Untested though.

As for how you can figure out which library you need to use for each Android API, I find the easiest way is to search for it on [cs.android.com](https://cs.android.com/search?q=AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels%20file:.*%5C.map%5C.txt&sq=&ssfr=1). For this one, I searched for `AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels file:.*\.map\.txt` (every NDK API is enumerated in a `*.map.txt` file). You can also use [this page](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis#bitmaps), but the code search is authoritative and makes it easier to look up an individual function rather than just "bitmap", in this case.