# Super fast Bitmap 180 degrees rotation using OpenCV on Android

Tags: android, opencv, optimization

I am looking for a fast way to rotate a `Bitmap` 180 degrees using OpenCV on Android. Also, the `Bitmap` may be rotated in place, i.e. without allocation of additional memory.

Here [riwnodennyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/986216/riwnodennyk) described different methods of rotating `Bitmap`s and compared their performances: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29734593/1707617. Here is GitHub repository for this study: https://github.com/riwnodennyk/ImageRotation.

This study doesn't include OpenCV implementation. So, I tried my own implementation of OpenCV rotator (only 180 degrees).

The best rotation methods for my test picture are as follows:

- OpenCV: 13 ms
- Ndk: 15 ms
- Usual: 29 ms

Because OpenCV performance looks very promising and my implementation seems to be unoptimized, I decided to ask you how to implement it better.

My implementation with comments:

```
@Override
public Bitmap rotate(Bitmap srcBitmap, int angleCcw) {
    Mat srcMat = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(srcBitmap, srcMat); // Possible memory allocation and copying
    
    Mat rotatedMat = new Mat();
    Core.flip(srcMat, rotatedMat, -1); // Possible memory allocation
    
    Bitmap dstBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBitmap.getWidth(), srcBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Unneeded memory allocation
    Utils.matToBitmap(rotatedMat, dstBitmap); // Unneeded copying

    return dstBitmap;
}
```

There are 3 places where, I suppose, unnecessary allocations and copying may take place.

Is it possible to get rid of theese unnecessary operations?

Comment: you oughta check what `bitmapToMat` does exactly. does it reuse the memory? cv::Mat can do that, it doesn't "own" the memory then. same goes for `matToBitmap`. if you have `srcBitmap`, and you allocate `dstBitmap`, and the Mat objects (I don't know) are reusing those pieces of memory, then that's probably the smallest amount of allocations you can get. I don't know if cv::flip is able to operate truly in-place. docs don't say. it might use multithreading, which your other methods might not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented fast bitmap rotation library.

**Performance (approximately):**

- 5 times faster than Matrix rotation method.
- 3.8 times faster than Ndk rotation method.
- 3.3 times faster than OpenCV rotation method.

https://github.com/ivankrylatskoe/fast-bitmap-rotation-lib